# symfony2.7 How to Use PHP's built-in Web Server

Tags: php, symfony

I have a PC with windows 8.1 and XAMPP v3.2.1 and it includes PHP 5.6.
I followed these steps from: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/web_server/built_in.html

```
php app/console server:run x.x.x.x:8000
```

The issue is, I can't run my symfony app in a web server, the error is:

> Built in server terminated unexpectedly

If I launch this command: `php app/console server:run`, everything is ok:

> Server running on http://127.0.0.1:8000

And this: `php app/console server:run 0.0.0.0:8000` => OK

My application isn't accessible with my local IP address.

Comment: use only http://localhost:port or 127.0.0.1:port

Answer (score 2):

I almost sure you're defining an invalid IP address.
You must define or loopback address (`localhost` or `127.0.0.1`) or your machine IP on local network (i.e: 192.168.25.7).
Also, if want more details on what is going on, run command passing "-vvv" (most verbose level):

```
$ bin/console -vvv server:run  192.168.25.6:8000
```

Comment: my ip address is valid. The issue is that i going to deploy my web application in windows server 2012 R2, but the problem is, my application can't run in a web server, it's only accesible in localhost.
**app/console:server:run** is only for development purpose.